# Show $ (2 - b^2c^2) (1 + b^2) \ge (b^2 + c^2)(b + c - 3)^2 $ in some range.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

Show $ F = (2 - b^2c^2) (1 + b^2) - (b^2 + c^2)(b + c - 3)^2 \ge 0$ in the following two ranges of $(b,c)$:

1. $b \in [0 \quad 1]$ and $0 \le c\le b$,
2. $b \in [1 \quad 1.2]$ and $0 \le c\le 3-2b$.

Equality occurs only at $(b,c)= (1,0)$.

This can be solved by treating $F$ as a polynomial in one of the variables (the other a parameter), and then using [Budan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budan%27s_theorem). This has been performed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3978107/317854), but this is a very lengthy business. Does someone have a more direct method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried multiplying everything out and just plugging in the conditions? I quickly checked 1. and it seems to work, I even get $F\geq1$ in that case.

Comment: @Proxava I wonder how you get $F\ge 1$, since for $(b,c)= (1,0)$ you have $F=0$.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the square in the second term.

Comment: @Andreas Nice. The Buffalo Way kills them.

Comment: @RiverLi Go ahead post BW as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Proof of* (1): Clearly, if $b = 0$, the inequality is true. Also, if $c = 0$, the inequality
becomes $(-b^2 + 4b + 2)(b-1)^2 \ge 0$ which is true.

If $b\in (0, 1]$ and $c\in (0, b]$, let $b = \frac{1}{1+s}, c = b \frac{1}{1+t}$ for $s, t \ge 0$.
The inequality becomes
$$\frac{1}{(1+s)^6(1+t)^4}[f(s,t) + 14s^4 - 3s^2 + 2s] \ge 0$$
where $f(s, t)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients. Thus, the inequality is true.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of* (2): If $b = 1$, the inequality becomes $c(1-c)(c^2 - 3c + 4) \ge 0$ which is true.
Also, if $c = 0$, the inequality
becomes $(-b^2 + 4b + 2)(b-1)^2 \ge 0$ which is true.

If $b\in (1, 6/5]$ and $c\in (0, 3-2b]$, let $b = 1 + \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{1+s}$
and $c = (3-2b)\frac{1}{1+t}$ for $s, t\ge 0$. The inequality becomes
$$\frac{1}{15625(1+s)^6(1+t)^4}g(s, t) \ge 0$$
where $g(s, t)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients. Thus, the inequality is true.

We are done.

Comment: Nice substuition River Li!(+1)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thanks. Although we can do it by hand here, usually the Buffalo Way requires the help of computer due to long expression.

Comment: :)  Even this solution will require some hardwork with hand wont it? do you think any elegant solution can be brought using convexity/concavity/mixed variables?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes, maybe ten minutes or twenty minutes. There should be simpler  solutions.

Comment: Nice solution. Fully expanded, the polynomial $f$ has 27 terms, and the polynomial $g$ has 32 terms.  But never mind, I do not think that an elegant solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer just a remark for the first case:

If we substitute $b=\frac{z}{z+y}$ and $c=\frac{y}{x+y}$ we get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282+-+%28z%2F%28z%2By%29%29%5E2%28y%2F%28x%2By%29%29%5E2%29+%281+%2B+z%C2%B2%2F%28z%2By%29%5E2%29+-+%28z%C2%B2%2F%28z%2By%29%5E2+%2B+%28y%2F%28x%2By%29%29%5E2%29%28z%2F%28z%2By%29+%2B+%28y%2F%28x%2By%29%29+-+3%29%5E2) .Remains to plays properly with the three variables or perhaps use Buffalo's way I don't know .

Hope you find something good !

Comment: Thank you for the remark.

Comment: @Andreas see my update ! Good day dear Andreas !